# Intersection Observer Not Working In Razor Page

Tags: javascript, razor-pages

I was trying to use intersection observers (javascript) in my razor pages but they don't seem to be working, I also couldn't find anything online where this is an issue.

```
// Intersection observer
const callback = function (entries) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            entry.target.classList.add('show');
            observer.unobserve(entry.target)
        }
    });
}
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback);
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('.hidden');
targets.forEach(target => {
    observer.observe(target);
})
```

I found a post with similar code (i just changed the classes' name) and it is not working.

I watched some yt videos and their code did not work for me either with exact copy pasting basically.

Any Ideas?

Comment: have you runned the chrome debugger or any logs from console

Answer (score -1):

This is not a full fledged answer, but I put the code in a `<script>@*code here*@</script>` and it works, may be related to linking the JS but none of my other pages have linking issues so idk.

Answer:

Still new to web stuff and you guys are ruthless...

All I had to do was disable caching through inspect element.

There was nothing wrong with the link to js.

Comment: you probably run that code "too early" when it doesn't work and `targets` is *empty*